# Unable to retrieve calendar data from freebusy query

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to get the busy free times from my calendar.
Here is my code:

```
var freeRequest = gapi.client.calendar.freebusy.query({
   timeMin: (new Date(2016, 3, 1)).toISOString(),
   timeMax: (new Date(2016, 3, 30)).toISOString()
});

freeRequest.execute(function(resp) {
   console.log(resp);
});
```

It returns the same results as I get from [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy/query#response). In both cases, I do not get any calendars back. Here is the response I do get:

```
{
  "kind": "calendar#freeBusy",
  "timeMin": "2016-05-01T04:00:00.000Z",
  "timeMax": "2016-05-30T05:00:00.000Z"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add items to your request like this:

```
var freeRequest = gapi.client.calendar.freebusy.query({
    items: [
      {id: "calendar id"}
    ],
    timeMin: (new Date(2016, 3, 1)).toISOString(),
    timeMax: (new Date(2016, 3, 30)).toISOString()
});
```

The calendar id can be found like [this](https://support.appmachine.com/hc/en-us/articles/203645966-Find-your-Google-Calendar-ID-for-the-Events-block).